# Assocation and Generalization between two classes

Tags: java, uml, model-associations, generalization

Can anyone give me example of class `B` which inherits from `A` and there is association between them and what pattern uses such bonds?

I am referring to the situation where `A` is generalization of `B` and exists association bond between them on UML diagram.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manager/Employee where the manager is an employee and has `n` employees  working for him.